# Termin vorschlagen: "...außer 12 Uhr bis 13 Uhr"

Tags: english-to-german, time, question, letter

I got an interview invitation . In email they ask what time is suitable for me.

**1. How to politely response to this invitation and give time slots I am
free?**

**Version A**

Für das persönliche Gespräch unterbreite ich Ihnen gerne folgende Terminvorschläge:

- Montag
- Dienstag

...

**Version B**

Wie würde es Ihnen in der diesen Woche am Freitag, den [Datum] oder alternativ am Mittwoch, den [Datum] passen? Zeitlich bin ich an beiden Tagen flexibel und richte mich gerne nach Ihnen.

**2. I will be free on Donnerstag, but I have an appointment at 12 pm.
How can I suggest this day?**

Am Donnerstag bin ich auch frei außer von 12 bis 13 Uhr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your suggestions are good, polite, and they work.

Which version to use is just a matter of personal taste. I would prefer Version B a slight bit because I thinks it's friendlier, but I know some of my colleagues would prefer A because they don't like reading long sentences, and in their opinion it's friendlier to make it easy for them to extract the important facts at a glance.

Small correction: "in der diesen Woche" should be "in dieser Woche".

Comment: did i write the answer for the second question correctly?

Comment: Yes. You could set an optional comma before außer, but it's really not needed and I wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

I would also use Version B but with this little change:

Am Donnerstag habe ich auch Zeit, außer zwischen 12 und 13 Uhr.