# How to say "I am available.." in German? (scheduling an appointment)

Tags: word-usage, phrase, phrase-request

I want to schedule an appointment at the dentist's.
Can I write something like this?

Guten Tag Herr Miller,

**Ich bin verfügbar:**

am Dienstag ab 11:00 – 15:00 Uhr

am Donnerstag ab 11:00 – 15:00 Uhr

am Freitag ab 11:00 – 15:00 Uhr

**Bitte schlagen Sie den Termin vor.**

**Ich freue mich auf Ihre Antwort.**

Donna Parker

My question is similar to this:[https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/70879/termin-vorschlagen-außer-12-uhr-bis-13-uhr](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/70879/termin-vorschlagen-au%C3%9Fer-12-uhr-bis-13-uhr)

but I want to use the different phrase.

Answer (score 1):

Your version works and is well understandable, but a bit uncommon in a few details for this situation:

a) it's much more common to phrase it like "Ich hätte Zeit:". If you make an appointment with the dentist you are not doing them a favour, but vice versa. As such "zur Verfügung stehen" does not quite fit here IMHO - it fits better when you offer your time for a service to someone else, thus when you quote your availability to a client, but not when you are the client yourself.

b) I'd leave out the "ab" in the time span you are available. It is either

> Donnerstag ab 11 Uhr (without any ending specified, but possibly implied by context)
> Donnerstag von 11 bis 16 Uhr
> Donnerstag 11 - 16 Uhr

c) You ask the person to suggest *an* appointment. It sounds a bit strange to my ears to ask for *the* appointment. Rather ask:

> Bitte schlagen Sie *einen* Termin vor

Comment: Donnerstag ab 11h? What's "h" here? Is it a shorter form of a word "Uhr"?

Comment: yes, "Uhr" is also often abbreviated in these situations by "h" - usually durations, though. Whether you want to add the minutes is also a matter of taste and mostly of needed accuracy. Your way to note the time is by no means worse or less common than mine - actually yours probably is better :) see https://www.fehler-haft.de/wissen/uhrzeit.html

Answer (score -2):

The canonical way is to write

> *Ich habe am Dienstag von 11:00 Uhr bis 15:00 Uhr, am Donnerstag ab 11:00 Uhr bis 15:00 Uhr, und am Freitag von 11:00 Uhr bis 15:00 Uhr Zeit.*

or shorter

> *Ich habe am Dienstag, Donnerstag und Freitag jeweils von 11:00 Uhr bis 15:00 Uhr Zeit.*

if the time of day is the same on all days. You can reorder it as *Ich habe Zeit am …* though it doesn't sound as natural.

And you may want to add the timezone. UTC+-xxx values are easier to decode than shortcuts as MST.

---

Don't put it as *verfügbar*. That's only good for tools and materials and thus self-degrading.

> über etwas verfügen — to possess something, to rule over something

> über jemanden verfügen — to rule over someone as if they were a tool

Especially women are called *verfügbar* when they are open for sex with anyone. I'm not really sure if that's an euphemism.

Comment: Your comments about "verfügbar" and especially women being open for sex is absolute nonsense. The term is used commonly when scheduling meetings, appointments and the like.

Comment: And it gives me shivers each time.

Comment: That may be - but language is, what people use. Rules of language are an afterthought. i.e. we used to write "Athem" and now write "Atem" - but still write "Thor" and not "Tor". We also wrote "Photograph" and now write "Fotograf" but still use "Graph" when we talk about the mathematical construct, not "Graf". You may find that "new" way whatever you want: wrong, annoying, inconsistent, ...  - fact is, people use it and if you deviate too much from that you won't be (easily) understood.