# Can I use "Ich bin erreichbar..." as "I'm available..." (scheduling an appointment)

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase, phrase-request

I want to schedule an appointment at the dentist's.
I read that "erreichbar sein" means "to be reachable" and you can use it when you talk over the phone, but I was wondering if I can say it instead of the phrase: "I'm available."
Can I write something like this?

Guten Tag Herr Miller,

**Ich bin erreichbar:**

am Dienstag von 11:00 bis 15:00 Uhr

am Donnerstag von 11:00 bis 15:00 Uhr

am Freitag von 11:00 bis 15:00 Uhr

Ich freue mich auf Ihre Antwort.

Donna Parker

My question is similar to the one I've already asked:[How to say "I am available.." in German? (scheduling an appointment)](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/72039/how-to-say-i-am-available-in-german-scheduling-an-appointment/72040?noredirect=1#comment172311_72040)

but I want to understand the difference between them and how to use them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'erreichbar sein' does not mean to be free to go, but be available to be visited or better contacted. It is most often used for communication like a call, email, or letter, giving the relevant contact info. It literally means that you can be reached.

> Zu Geschäftszeiten erreichen Sie mich unter Telefon 4711653 oder Email Info@example.com.

> Guten Tag, Sie haben vor zwei Stunden versucht mich telefonisch zu erreichen. Jetzt bin ich für Sie da, was kann ich für Sie tun?

Answer (score 3):

*Erreichbar sein* comes from the Verb "erreichen", which means "to reach" or "to contact". If you call someone by phone or send him an e-mail and he indeed answers, you have him "erreicht".

To "be available", on the other hand, would be "*verfügbar sein*". It comes from the Verb "verfügen" (to direct, to dispose, to have sth. available) and means you have time for someone else to schedule an appointment with you, visit you, contact you or similar.

To schedule an appointment with your dentist (which means meeting him in person) you will want to be "verfügbar" at the time the appointment is scheduled. You might be "erreichbar" (that means being able to pick up the phone, read an e-mail, etc. to schedule said appointment) at some other times, maybe including the ones you are "verfügbar" at.